# Is it possible to check drives SMART attributes from a USB/eSATA enclosure?

Tags: hardware, usb, sata, drive, esata

I use USB external drives on a daily basis and I would like to be able to check on their integrity. I recently happened to discover I was unable to read SMART attributes from them.

I wonder if there were external enclosures allowing the OS the check the SMART attributes, either USB or eSATA and if this was a hardware and/or software limitation(s).

I suspect it is hardware-related limitation of certain USB enclosures but could not find a real answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can obtain SMART attributes if the USB adapter/enclosure supports UASP, [USB Attached SCSI Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI). Older enclosures may not support this protocol and may only have proprietary interfaces to SMART, or none at all.

The Linux `smartctl` command has some support for old proprietary USB enclosures, so you may get lucky. For all the gory details, see the section of the `smartctl` man page explaining its `-d` option, which you can use to specify the type of interface if necessary.

If `smartctl` doesn't autodetect your UASP enclosure, pass `-d sat` on the command line. For example:

```
smartctl -d sat -a /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Regarding enclosures supporting eSATA only or in addition to USB, you can obtain SMART attributes "almost directly"?

Comment: @Paradox If it's eSATA then there is no problem, that will just happen normally. It's USB enclosures that you might have a problem with. eSATA is literally SATA with a different physical connector. USB is a whole other protocol, and SATA must be tunneled over it, which is what UASP does.

Comment: @Michael_Hampton That's what I thought. Thanks.